# How to match rows in a MySql table with a JSON data of 200 records as input in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a database having 10000 users with unique phone numbers.And when ever a new user registers I'm trying to match all his contacts (nearly 200 to 500) with my existing data so that I can find his friends (like whats app)

Currently I m doing using foreach and its very slow, so I need help in finding a reliable solution for this which can reduce the time taken for multiple queries.

Please find the code below that i m using.

```
$rawdata= file_get_contents('php://input');
$Matchedcontacts = array();
$jsonArray = json_decode($rawdata);
foreach ( $jsonArray as $value)
  {

  $contactNumber = ($value->num);
  $emil= ($value->email);
  $name=mysql_query("select * from TBL_USER where  phone='".$contactNumber ."' OR email='".$email."'");
  while ($nameres= mysql_fetch_array($name))
  {
   $Matchedcontacts [] = array('username'=>$nameres['username'], 'userid'=>$nameres['c_id']);
  }

}

echo json_encode ($Matchedcontacts );
```

EDIT: also I'm passing a local id with the each record I'm sending. So after a match, how can I map the matched record with the particular local ID?

Comment: You can do that in 1 query using `WHERE phone IN (phone1, ..., phoneN)'. You should build an array with all numbers and use that. And you should switch to a prepared statement with PDO or mysql to protect yourself from sql injection. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider importing the contacts list into a (temporary?) table, and use join.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `phone` is an `INDEX` of some sort, then this should be faster by passing all the values at once

```
$data = array();
foreach( $jsonArray as $value) $data[] = mysql_real_escape_string($value->num);
$name = mysql_query("select * from TBL_USER where  phone IN ('". implode("', '", $data) ."'");
```

Also, this is your [obligatory mysql_ function deprecation notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Consider switching to `mysqli_`

Answer (score 0):

One very simple optimization would be to optimize your SQL Query down to a single query

First build a list of contact numbers from `$jsonArray` and then use that array in the following SQL Query

```
select email, username, userid from TBL_USER where  phone IN ( 'phone num 1', 'phone num 2' )
```

Also remember to escape those phone numbers so that you don't have SQL Injections!

Comment: thanks for the solution , let me give it a try :)  Also , if i want to match if either phone or email is matching, can i do like this ? select email, username, userid from TBL_USER where  phone IN ( 'phone num 1', 'phone num 2' ) OR email IN ('email 1', 'email 2' )

Comment: Yes that would return any user that has a phone number in the phone list OR an email in the email list